# add data in listview from another activity error

Tags: android, listview

i want to ask..i have 2 form , say it form1 and form2 and i have listview on form1, i want to set data from form2..so i just create some dummy project to try it and i wonder why wont work..

so this is my code on **form2** :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.form2);             


    ArrayList<MyClass> searchResults = GetSearchResults();                
      form1.listview.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, searchResults));
}

private ArrayList<MyClass> GetSearchResults(){
         ArrayList<MyClass> results = new ArrayList<MyClass>();

         MyClass sr = new MyClass();
         sr.setJumlah_menu("Justin Schultz");
         sr.setNama_menu("San Francisco, CA");

         results.add(sr);          

         return results;
  }
```

this is **my adapter** code :

```
public class AdapterListPemesananMenu extends BaseAdapter {
    private static ArrayList<MenuInputClass> searchArrayList;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public AdapterListPemesananMenu(Context context, ArrayList<MenuInputClass> results) {
        searchArrayList = results;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }



    public AdapterListPemesananMenu(OnClickListener onClickListener,
            ArrayList<MenuInputClass> searchResults) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    public int getCount() {
        return searchArrayList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return searchArrayList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_pemesananmenu_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtNamaMasuk);
            holder.txtCityState = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtJumlahMasuk);
            //holder.txtPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtName.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getNama_menu());
        holder.txtCityState.setText(searchArrayList.get(position)
                .getJumlah_menu());


        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtCityState;

    } 
}
```

when i go to form2 from form1, its always force closed..

whats wrong with my code?

when i try the code(from form2) on form1 its work well..

this is from logcat :

```
10-22 04:33:30.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15247): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 04:33:30.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15247): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aplikasipemesananmenu/list_pemesananmenu_view.SingleListView_Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-22 04:33:30.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
10-22 04:33:30.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
10-22 04:33:30.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-22 04:33:30.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15247):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
10-22 04:33:30.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15247):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-22 04:33:30.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15247):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-22 04:33:30.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3693)
10-22 04:33:30.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15247):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 04:33:30.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15247):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-22 04:33:30.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15247):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
10-22 04:33:30.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15247):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
10-22 04:33:30.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15247):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 04:33:30.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15247): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-22 04:33:30.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15247):    at list_pemesananmenu_view.SingleListView_Activity.onCreate(SingleListView_Activity.java:67)
10-22 04:33:30.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15247):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-22 04:33:30.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
10-22 04:33:30.647: E/AndroidRuntime(15247):    ... 11 more
10-22 04:33:31.958: E/DataRouter(125): smd_file_fd = 16 and external_file_fd = 24
10-22 04:33:31.958: E/DataRouter(125): ==KDW(3)== smd_new_status = (358)
10-22 04:33:31.958: E/DataRouter(125): ==KDW(4)== smd_new_status = (320)
10-22 04:33:31.958: E/DataRouter(125): DCD pinstatus is ON
```

any help would be appreciate thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you set form1 on the form2.onCreate() method?
Seems like the NPE is on the form1.listview.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, searchResults)); like.

I think you shouldn't use an activity object within another one as the system could kill the used object whenever it wants. Take a look at the Activity lifecile at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html and http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html.

Use a custom Application class to pass data between activities and the Activity.onResume() method to use the new data on the listview on the called Activity.

Just ask for same example code if you don't know how to make it.

Eddited (code below)

Create your custom Application object:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    Object mData;

    public Object getData() {
        return mData;
    }
    public void setData(Object data) {
        mData = data;
    }

}
```

Use it in the manifest:

```
 <application
        android:name="my.apppkg.MyApplication"

   ...
 </application>
```

And create the two activities. Form1 as the "consumer":

```
public class Form1 extends Activity {
    MyApplication mApp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mApp = (MyApplication)getApplication();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Object data = mApp.getData();
        if (data != null) {

            // Do whatever you want with the data

        } else {
            // No data
        }

    }
    ...
}
```

and Form2 as the "producer":

```
public class Form2 extends Activity {
    MyApplication mApp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mApp = (MyApplication)getApplication();

    }

    ...
    /**
     * Data generation method. Calls to Form1 once the data is set.
     * Call it here or from wherever you need it to (Buttons onClick events, ListViews onItemListClick, etc)
     */
    private void processAndSendData() {
        Object newData = ...; // Get the data from your sources

        mApp.setData(newData);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Form1.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Of course, change the type of mData in MyApplication class (Object in the example) for whatever you need.

Comment: if i use onResume() method, the user must go to the activity to get the data added right?(in this case,its means i put onResume() method on form1). if i want add the data just on form2 without go to form1 how to make it?thank you!!